# Why does not the order of events in Windows forms match the documentation?

Tags: c#

When leaving a tab page, I want to validate some text boxes. To do this, I want to use the Validating event and the Leave event (fired by the tab page, not the text boxes). What confuses me is that the event order according to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

doesn't match what I experience using breakpoints.

According to the page above, the event order is as follow:

Enter, GotFocus, Leave, Validating, Validated, LostFocus.

But my breakpoints on Leave and Validating comes in this order:

Validating, Leave.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I get Leave, Validating, Validated.

Comment: The order on the link is when a form gets constructed  (startup) and disposed (shutdown).  It doesn't show events like mouse click.

Comment: @jdweng The second section does.

Comment: @Llama Are you using a tab control, or some other control?

Comment: Maybe link is old and Microsoft changed order.  I would assume it makes more send to validate before leave, but some people may argue the opposite.  What happens if somebody makes a change just at the time of leaving.  It would then be possible to leave with an error.  Then others would say the leave should just leave and not do anything else.

Comment: I was using a TabControl with a text box on the page and events on the TabPage.

Comment: @Llama Ok, thanks for you input. Do you have any events attached to the text box, or just the tabpage? How many tabpages do you have? In my case, I have two pages, and I'm only interested in validating when leaving the second one, so I have no events attached to the first page.

Comment: Post some code that reproduces your complaint, so that we can try it with copy paste, not this endless back n forthing trying to make sure we've got our stuff set up like your stuff

Comment: I had two. Events on the first page. No events on anything else.